# how can i integrate moodle with joomla?

Tags: joomla, moodle

I tried to use joomdle component but whenever I try to configure **mod_joomdle_courses**, I got 
XML-RPC Error (7021): The transport method you are trying to use is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://www.joomdle.com/index.php/en/forum/5-r022-and-earlier/65-solved-error-xml-rpc-7021), you need to add your public IP into the XML-RPC hosts and ensure the host is "trusted".